# Generics/Interfaces and Tree Structures in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, tree

I am trying to create a tree structure (a binary tree) that is capable of holding two different types of class (a sphere and a rectangle).

For obvious reasons my sphere and rectangle will have different methods for getting their size (getSize()) and I also intend to have a constructor (for both classes) thats takes two objects (two spheres OR two rectangles) and combines them to create a larger sphere or rectangle.

How should I approach coding a node so that it can store either a sphere or a rectangle at a node calling the appropriate methods when required?

Would a simple interface accomplish this if i cast objects to the type i need?

Thanks,

DMcB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create three classes.
An abstract class Shape that contains all common code for rectangles and spheres.

```
public abstract class Shape{
   // contains all common code related to shapes
   // such as child elements
   Shape parentNode; // This will help navigate up
   List<Shape> children; // This will help navigate down the tree
   // Define, merge, split methods which are common to all shapes
   // define shape specific methods
}
public class Rectangle : Shape{
   // Implement shape's abstract methods for this class
}

public class Sphere : Shape{
   // Implement shape's abstract methods for this class
}
```

All shape specific methods should be left abstract such as `getSize()`, `drawShape()`, `mergeShape()`.
Also, maybe not relevant but [the Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) might be of good use for this problem

Answer (score 3):

> Would a simple interface accomplish this if i cast objects to the type i need?

An interface `Shape` would seem appropriate. If done right, you won't need a cast at all when inserting an item.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an interface where you store the common methods and implement them in each class. Then polymorphism will take care of calling the appropriate method at runtime.